# Make a line in faceted ggplot2 with width from dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2, line

I am looking to create a graph that looks like the second picture below, using data provided below. However, I can't get the width of the lines to correspond to the axis, "B", and to take the values from datlines$width. What I'd like is for geom_hline (or maybe geom_ribbon?) to read the widths from the data.frame "datlines" and create a line where the width is equal to the number provided in datlines$width. So far I haven't been able to make it work, even if I specify "size = width" in the geom_hlines call.

Any suggestions? Even if I get the size = width part to mirror my datlines data.frame, the size of the line doesn't correspond to the y-axis.

I'd be fine if I had to tell ggplot2 the upper and lower boundaries of the grey area, too.

```
dat
  A B      C
1 1 2 Facet1
2 1 3 Facet2
3 2 4 Facet1
4 2 5 Facet2

datlines
  int      C width
1   3 Facet1   1.0
2   4 Facet2   0.5
```

My data and code for the fist graph below

```
dat <- data.frame(A = c(1, 1, 2, 2), B = c(2, 3, 4, 5), C = c("Facet1", "Facet2"))
dat
datlines <- data.frame(int = c(3, 4), C = c("Facet1", "Facet2"), width = c(1, 0.5))
datlines
plot <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = A, y = B)) +  
  geom_hline(data = datlines, aes(yintercept = int), colour = "gray") + geom_point() + facet_grid(. ~ C) 
plot
```

Graph that results from the code I provided:
[image: Figure 1]

Graph that I want:
[image: Figure 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `geom_rect`

```
dat <- data.frame(A = c(1, 1, 2, 2), B = c(2, 3, 4, 5), 
                  C = c("Facet1", "Facet2"), 
                  width=c(1,0.5), int = c(3, 4))
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x=A,y=B)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(~C) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=-Inf, xmax=Inf, 
                ymin=int-width/2, ymax=int+width/2), fill = 'grey')
```

[image]

Comment: This works great, thank you! I like this answer because keeping everything in the same data.frame is nice and clean - I didn't think to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use geom_rect, but you'll have to modify ymin and ymax first:

```
datlines$int2 <- c(2.5, 3.75)

ggplot() + 
geom_point(data=dat, aes(x = A, y = B)) +  
geom_rect(data=datlines, aes(ymin=int2, ymax=int2+width, xmin=-Inf, xmax=+Inf), fill='grey', alpha=1)  + 
facet_grid(. ~ C)
```

Comment: This is also a helpful solution that keeps the data frames separate if that were easier in future.